# Safest, Easiest Way to Format & Mount Multiple Hard Drives without losing data?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, steam

Okay, I'm trying to make a switch to Ubuntu from Windows. I understand the file structure is different and different terms are used, which I'm okay with. I also have no problem with waiting on copying/pasting from drive to drive.

I have 4 drives in all: firstly is what I call my system drive which would contain the OS, OS updates, and related files (it's a 120GB SSD), then I have 3 other drives for anything else - 1x3TB, 1x4TB, and 1x1TB respectively. I want to mount them each in a way that I can install stuff like Steam to my 3TB drive. Or should I just stop using my SSD for the system like I did with Windows and reinstall to one of my other drives?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're wanting to do, but I'll have a stab at it.

If you want to keep all your windows files, simplest method is to physically remove the SSD from your system. Now install Ubuntu to whichever drive you choose (1Tb, 3Tb or 4Tb). After you've installed you can put your SSD back into your system.

When you boot into Ubuntu you will still be able to see all your windows files, however if you want to run Windows apps you will need to install WINE in Ubuntu. This can be done through the Software Center or through the command-line (open a Terminal and type `sudo apt-get install wine`